# Polarion document baseline with links in description field

Tags: polarion

I have a generic LiveDoc in Polarion which contains a series of referenced requirements. Recently I started to insert links into the description of some of the requirements to make it easier to navigate from one requirement to another. However, I've discovered that when I baseline the document the links in the description don't get updated to point to the baselined version of the requirement, but the links (to the same requirement) in the Linked Work Items section are updated to include the baseline revision.

Is there a way to get the links in the description to point to the baselined revision like the ones in the Linked Work Items section?

I'm using Polarion 21 R1 if that matters.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. I doubt you get this working 100%. HTML is notoriously hard to parse(complete and correctly), so you should avoid this workflow.
Use Linked Workitems instead and use the new Collection Feature, which most probably does what you need.

Also while it is possible to link to older / specific revisions (of artefacts) in Polarion, I never found a scenario which was maintainable and useful in same time.
Note that Revisions get big very fast (5-7 digits). Comparing or updating these links is very error prone and demanding work, full of devastating pitfalls.

We follow the approach to keep items unchanged after release and create new items instead of changing existing ones. We have then more WIs but Polarion's UI (and most peoples head) can deal with large number of WIs better than with versioned links.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced 21 R1, but I have tested this method on 22/2304 versions.
Once you insert link of WI in WI's description field, it renders to its Icon with href.

For example, if you insert below URL into description of WI...

```
http://{host}/polarion/#/project/{projectName}/workitem?id={workItemId}
```

[image: Example1]

For another example, if you insert below URL into description of WI...

```
http://{host}/polarion/#/project/{projectName}/workitem?id={workItemId}&revision={yourtargetrevision}
```

[image: Example2]

Maybe the second example is what you are looking for.

Comment: Jae, thanks for your comment, I hadn't thought of doing that. I'll give it a go.